# JsonCPP throwing a logic error:requires objectValue or nullValue

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

```
void exp::example(std::string &a, std::string &b)
{   
    if (m_root.isObject() && m_root.isMember(a))
    {
        if (m_root[a].isMember(b))
        {
            m_root[a].append(b);
        }

    }
    else
    {  
        m_root[a] = Json::arrayValue;
        m_root[a].append(b);

    }
}
```

(m_root is defind in the hpp)

When I'm running this code I get the logic error:
in Json::Value::find(key, end, found): requires objectValue or nullValue.
I found out that I got this error from this if:
`if (m_root[a].isMember(b))`

I don't understand why do I get this error there, I used the same function in the if above him and I didn't get this error.

P.S the function is working until it enter the nested if, example:

| a | b | m_root |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "hey" | "a1" | `{"hey":["a1"]}` |
| "bye" | "a2" | `{"hey":["a1"], "bye":["b1"]}` |
| "cye" | "a3" | `{"hey":["a1"], "bye":["b1"], "cye":["a3"]}` |
| "hey" | "a4" | `error: in Json::Value::find(key, end, found): requires objectValue or nullValue` |

I get the error only in the 4th call.
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 4th iteration you access the `m_root["hey"]` object which is of type `arrayValue`. Those values are not supported by the `isMember` method.

You'll have to find the value in the array in another way. I suggest iterating over the array, in something like:

```cpp
bool is_inside_array(const Json::Value &json_array, const string& value_to_find) 
{
      for (const Json::Value& array_value: json_array) {
           if (array_value.asString() == value_to_find) {
                return true;
           }
      }
      return false;
}
```

Then replace the inner `if` with:

```cpp
if (is_inside_array(m_root[a], b))
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without iterating over the array?
Some kind JsonCPP function?

Comment: From what's written in [here](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/362) I guess the answer is no :(